# Unable to define a protocol with a NSObject as a parameter

Tags: objective-c

For the life of me I cannot figure out what is wrong with this protocol declaration. I get the following errors on the line right after @requred:

Expected * before *
Expected ')' before 'MyService'

```
@protocol MyServiceDelegate

@required
- (void)requestFinished:(MyService *)service;
@end

@interface MyService : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <MyServiceDelegate>delegate;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSURLConnection *connection;

@end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When compiling `MyServiceDelegate` protocol, the compiler does not know about `MyService` class. You can use a forward declaration to solve this:

```
@class MyService;

@protocol MyServiceDelegate
// implementation continues
```

Answer (score 1):

At the point of the error, the compiler doesn't know about your MyService class - add

```
@class MyService;
```

before

```
@protocol MyServiceDelegate
```

and it should work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `@class MyServive;` before the protocol. You use it inside the protocol.